# Как поменять порядок вывода записей из базы

Tags: php

Привет всем!
Скажите пожалуйста. Как поменять поменять список записей из базы mysql .
Простой пример у меня есть блог на котором я вывожу записи из базы, но они выводяться от старого к новому, а хотелось бы от нового с старому. Спасибо

вот пример `$result4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data   WHERE  cat='$cat'   ",$db);`что и как мне поменять

Comment: `ODER BY id DESC`

Comment: Вопрос вам надо поменять и описать структуру данных и указать поле по которому надо сортировать. А еще было бы неплохо почитать документацию по SQL...

Comment: из базы выводяться так 1 2 3 4 а мне надо чтобы вышло так 4 3 2 1

Answer (score 2):

```
$result4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data   WHERE  cat='$cat' ODER BY id DESC ",$db);
```

Вместо id вставьте имя поля по которому хотите сортировать.

Comment: Спасибо большое за полный ответ

Comment: за `mysql_query` к вам придет г-н Ипатьев и поругает сильно